# content-hover does not work with mouse click on event listener

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code.

```
const pin = tooltip.querySelector('.pin');
    const content = tooltip.querySelector('.tooltip-content');
    pin.addEventListener("click", () => {
        tooltip.classList.add("active");
    });
    pin.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            if (!tooltip.classList.contains("content-hover")) {
                tooltip.classList.remove("active");
            }
        }, 1250);
    });
```

Currently when I click on the event the content pops up but when I hover over the content it should remove the timeout. However that is not the case. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into `clearTimeout();` and how it works. The code you posted is incomplete and it's not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve.